# How to handle switch cases in Meteor templates

Tags: templates, meteor, handlebars.js

What's the best way to handle a switch case in a template (eg: a button with 4 possible states)? It seems wrong to pull the html out into a helper, but it feels just as bad to put the logic into the template...

**Edit:**

As you can see, putting the html in a helper is far from ideal, but changing a class, a tag-name, properties, and content, would make the template wholly unreadable.

```
Template.nextMeetup.helpers({
    rsvpButton: function(rsvp) {
        var button;

        switch(rsvp){
            case 'yes':
                button = '<a ' + this.event_url + 'class="rsvp btn btn-success pull-right" title="visit event page" target="_blank"><i class="icon-check"></i> I\'m Attending</a>';
            break;
            case 'maybe':
                button = '<a ' + this.event_url + 'class="rsvp btn btn-warning pull-right" title="visit event page" target="_blank"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> I might go</a>';
            break;
            case 'no':
                button = '<a ' + this.event_url + 'class="rsvp btn btn-danger pull-right" title="visit event page" target="_blank"><i class="icon-remove"></i> I\'m not going</a>';
            break;
            case 'none':
                button = '<a ' + this.event_url + 'class="rsvp btn btn-inverse pull-right" title="visit event page" target="_blank"><i class="icon-spinner"></i> I havn\'t decided</a>';
            break;
            default:
                button = '<button class="rsvp signIn btn btn-disabled pull-right">Sign in to RSVP</button>';
        }
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(button);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure what you’re trying to output, but a helper that evaluates equality will likely be involved. Put this in one of your project’s client-loaded JavaScript files:

```
Template.registerHelper("equals", function (a, b) {
  return (a == b);
});
```

Then you can create something similar to a switch-case structure using `if` blocks and your new `equals` helper. For example, if you're storing the state of a button in a variable named `btnState` and the possible values are `1`, `2` or `3`:

```
<button class="{{#if equals btnState 1}}btn-active{{/if}}
               {{#if equals btnState 2}}btn-inactive{{/if}}
               {{#if equals btnState 3}}btn-disabled
               {{else}}btn-default{{/if}}">
```

If you want `switch`-`case`'s ability to short-circuit further tests after it hits a true value, and/or a default case at the end, the way to do so is with an ugly set of nested `if`-`else` blocks:

```
<button class="{{#if equals btnState 1}}
                 btn-active
               {{else}}
                 {{#if equals btnState 2}}
                   btn-inactive
                 {{else}}
                   {{#if equals btnState 3}}
                     btn-disabled
                   {{else}}
                     btn-default
                   {{/if}}
                 {{/if}}
               {{/if}}">
```

This example is almost trivially simple; I’m assuming that you’re using this as a control structure for a large template, where instead of something like `btn-default` you have dozens of lines of HTML.

If you really are using it for short snippets of text like CSS class names, you could instead create a helper that maps a set of cases with a set of strings to be returned. For example (CoffeeScript):

```
Template.registerHelper "switch", (input, cases, output, def) ->
  # input is the variable we're comparing, i.e. switch(input)
  # cases is an EJSON-stringified array, i.e. case "foo", case "bar"
  # output is an EJSON-stringified array of strings to return for each case
  # def (default) is a string to return if none of the cases are met

  # Validate input, convert EJSON strings into arrays:
  unless input? and _.isString(cases) and _.isString(output)
    return ""
  cases = EJSON.parse cases
  output = EJSON.parse output
  unless _.isArray(cases) and _.isArray(output) and 
    cases.length is output.length
      return ""

  # Evaluate each case, returning as soon as the first case is true:
  for value, index in cases
    return output[index] if input is value

  # If we've made it this far, none of the cases were met; return def (default):
  if def? and _.isString(def) then return def else return ""
```

And to use it:

```
{{switch btnState "[1,2,3]"
  "[\"btn-active\",\"btn-inactive\",\"btn-disabled\"]" "btn-default"}}
```

Handlebars doesn’t allow passing arrays or objects into helpers, hence the contortions with JSON strings passed as parameters and then parsed.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response, but as I feared the answer seems to be: there is no good way :( The if/else/switch in the middle of the template already looks pretty messy, and that's with only a single property changing (I intend to classes, properties, and content). The "switch helper" looks more reasonable, but seems brittle and contrived. I guess I was hoping there was a common practice for handling something like this.

Comment: You can still separate content from logic. You can make a set of subtemplates (partials) for each of your buttons. Then if you want to use your helper, replace the HTML strings with `Template.btnYes({rsvp: rsvp})` or `Meteor.render(function() { Template.btnYes({rsvp: rsvp}) })`. Or make a partial called `button` that uses the ugly if-else block, and include sub-partials for each button. Include it via `{{> button}}`

Comment: I never thought to reference a template from inside a helper, thanks, I think that will work well.

Comment: I think for the general cases, the `equals` helper is the best option. It's essentially just a shortcut for creating boolean variables for each possible value before rendering the template, e.g. `isBtnState1`, `isBtnState2`, etc., which is the Handlebars-recommended way of handling this for simple cases.

Comment: In order for this to work for me, I had to add parentheses around the `equals` statement like so: `{{#if (equals btnState 1)}}btn-active{{/if}}`.

These are needed because `equals` is a subexpression (http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions)

Answer (score 7):

**Use one template per button and an additional dynamic template**

Your template helper, returning the dynamic template:

```
Template.nextMeetup.helpers({
    rsvpButtonTemplate: function(rsvp) {
        switch(rsvp){
            case 'yes':   return Template.buttonYes;
            case 'maybe': return Template.buttonMaybe;
            case 'no':    return Template.buttonNo;
            case 'none':  return Template.buttonNone;
        }
    }
});
```

Your main template, calling the template helper:

```
<template name="myPage">
    ...
    {{> rsvpButtonTemplate}}
    ...
</template>
```

Your 4 buttons:

```
<template name="buttonYes">
    <a {{event_url}} class="rsvp btn btn-success pull-right" title="visit event page" target="_blank"><i class="icon-check"></i> I'm Attending</a>
</template>
<template name="buttonMaybe">
    <a {{event_url}} class="rsvp btn btn-warning pull-right" title="visit event page" target="_blank"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> I might go</a>
</template>
<template name="buttonNo">
    <a {{event_url}} class="rsvp btn btn-danger pull-right" title="visit event page" target="_blank"><i class="icon-remove"></i> I'm not going</a>
</template>
<template name="buttonNone">
    <a {{event_url}} class="rsvp btn btn-inverse pull-right" title="visit event page" target="_blank"><i class="icon-spinner"></i> I havn't decided</a>
</template>
```